# Ember.js slow response from server, error `The adapter operation timed out`

Tags: ember.js, active-model-serializers

There is an ember application with quite slow server-side app.
One of the server api endpoints returns response in ~2 minutes by some circumstances.

In such cases I see an error in my browser console: `The adapter operation timed out`.

Is it possible to tweak ember.js api adapter timeout or somehow make ember app to interact with such slow endpoints?
I've tried to set `ajaxOption` in the `ActiveModelAdapter`, but it still does not work.

```
let AMAdapter = ActiveModelAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
  ajaxOptions(url, type, options) {
    let hash = this._super(url, type, options);
    hash.timeout = 200000;
    return hash;
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try override the ajaxOptions in the Rest Adapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RestAdapter.extend({
  ajaxOptions(url, type, options) {
    let hash = this._super(url, type, options);
    hash.timeout = 5000;
    return hash;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already tried this approach. I updated my question.